How to pass sensitive data to a new window in JavaScript
I launch a new browser window from a parent window with:
window.open(url, "MyAppTitle", "width=300, height=600, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no");

The child window needs a token (like a password), to establish a connection to a web service. To send the token from the parent to the child I use:
window.tokenString = "mytoken";

where mytoken is the token that needs to be transferred to the other window.
Then, in the other window, I retrieve the token with:
var retrievedToken = window.opener.tokenString;

Everything works fine in desktop browsers, but in mobile browsers it doesn't work. To make it work in mobile browsers I can save the token to localStorage with:
localStorage.setItem("tokenString", "mytoken");

then get the value with:
var retrievedToken = localStorage.getItem("tokenString");

The problem with this approach is that it is less safe. Even if I delete the password (with localStorage.remove("tokenString")) immediately after it is used to make the connection, there are still a few seconds where it is saved to the browser's storage.
I also tried other suggestions like:
var newWindow = window.open(url, "MyAppTitle", "width=300, height=600, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no");

newWindow.tokenString = "mytoken";

Then, in the new window, retrieve it with:
window.tokenString

or
var newWindow = window.open(url, "MyAppTitle", "width=300, height=600, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no");

newWindow["tokenString"] = "mytoken";

Then, in the new window, retrieve it with:
window["tokenString"]

but they don't work in mobile browsers. The only thing that works there is to use localStorage to store the token and then delete it after it has been used to establish the connection. Yet, this doesn't seem very safe. I know that passing the data with the first method isn't very safe either, but in that case it doesn't get saved to the browser's storage. Passing the data as a query parameter added to the URL is also not safe. My question is: what would be the best way to pass the sensitive string from the parent window to the child window, so that it works in desktop and mobile browsers ?
Thank you.
Later Edit: I changed the wording a bit to make the post clearer.

Use postMessage, that's pretty much why it exists: if you control the code on both pages, that's the proper way to make them talk to each other.

"The problem with this approach is that it is less secure"... you're writing client-side JavaScript, there are no secure values

Does this answer your question? Encrypting and Decryption Local storage values

Why are you trying to send the password to the window - can't you just have the user log in/authenticate on the base page, and then check that they've already authenticated in the new window? To echo the concern elsewhere in the thread if you're doing anything involving passwords/auth without using backend code, absolutely nothing about your application is secure.

@JonSG thank you for your reply. I think encrypting the string before storing it to localStorage can work, but I'll have to test and see if it affects the page loading speed.

@jmcgriz I never said I'm doing everything client-side. Or that the password is used to authenticate logged in users. I know how that's done.

Well everyone here is making that assumption because if you have a backend, you should at the very least be able to create a session for your user that lives serverside and have no need to pass anything between windows

@jmcgriz Yes, the app has a PHP back-end and everything works fine there. I'm not trying to authenticate users on my back-end. I'm trying to authenticate the app to a third party web service that requires a password. That can't be done with a session ID as you suggest.

It can and absolutely should be done that way https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

If you need further proof, there are plenty of examples of people trying to write code to get around the fact that php session variables persist between tabs/windows of a browser unless you intentionally go incognito https://groups.google.com/g/washington-dcphp-group/c/GO3ookb7zsQ?pli=1

@jmcgriz No, in my case, where an external web service is involved, with a specific type of authentication, it can't be done with session IDs.

Ok. Well I encourage you to spend some more time with that first link to understand why it would work and how it will help you. Good luck out there

@jmcgriz No, as I said, it won't work with session IDs in this situation.

I'm not talking about session IDs, I'm talking about storing variables in the session. You can literally use $_SESSION["servicepass"] to get and set the value, and then purge it once you're done with it. It's no more or less secure than passing through the window open

Thank you "Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans" for your message. Indeed, the generic solution for this problem is to use the postMessage() method:
On the parent window add:
var windpop = window.open(url, "MyAppTitle", "width=300, height=600, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no");
windpop.postMessage("mytoken", window.location.origin);

then, on the child window add:
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
   if (event.origin == window.location.origin) {
       var retrievedToken = event.data;
       /* use retrievedToken to connect to web service, etc. */
   }
}, false);

In my case both windows are on the same domain. This is why before getting the token I verified if the base of the popup's URL (window.location.origin) is the same as that of the window who opened the popup (event.origin).
However, nowadays many users have their browsers configured to block popups. When the browser blocks popups, the windpop variable from above is null and it remains null even after the new window is loaded completely. So, windpop.postMessage() is never triggered and the child window doesn't get any data from the parent window.

Just to repeat what was already said in the comments. There is no such thing like secure data in JavaScript. In the browsers developer tools you can watch each variable and even all code and do with it whatever you want.

@Thallius I know that. However, in my case, in the parent window I get the password through an AJAX call from the server, and I need to pass it as fast and as safely as possible to the child window, which sends it to the web service just once, then deletes it and that's it. If stored in the browser's storage for a long time, it's less safe than when it's passed directly with postMessage() to the child window. The only problem is when users have their browsers configured to block popups and postMessage() can't be used.

when you say "get the password through AJAX from a server", it suggests your storing the password as a plain text value on the server, which is just insane and you should never ever do that. You should be storing a hash on the server and authenticating the user with the hash. There should never ever be a reason to store a password. You should instead be passing your most recent Authentication Token to the window to call which ever service you need to call. This is all kinds of wrong. I'd suggest reading up on alternative approaches that would better protect you and your users.

https://thenewstack.io/best-practices-for-storing-access-tokens-in-the-browser/ example of sharing access token across browser tabs, should apply to windows.

@Emile the password is encrypted on the server. And yes, I need it as it is and not only its hash.

As far as you fetch the password from the server everyone can see it in the browsers developer tools. It doesn’t matter if you transfer it quickly to another site and delete it. It’s there and it is readable for everyone who has just a little bit of developer knowledge. What you are doing is wrong and should never be done.

@Thallius I don't think you understood my use case. The user who uses the app will see all the sensitive data in the browser. The user is in fact the one who first saves the password to the database on the Settings page of the app. So, obviously he knows the password. The only problem is if an intruder gets remote access to his browser while starting the application. The goal is to minimize the risk of an intruder getting the password while it is used to authenticate the app to the web service. And in this case a hash cannot be used instead of the real password.

I understand. You store a real password in your database. Hopefully I will never use your app….

@Thallius Please don't pretend to know the details of my use case when you don't.

We're all on the same page here except for you, and we all hope we never have to use anything you've built if this is your idea of security. If you would like us to understand your use case, then explain it

@jmcgriz Yes, session variables like $_SESSION["servicepass"] could be used and they seem better than passing the data in JavaScript from parent window to child window. I would have used this method if I had more control over the code. The problem is that my app has to be installed into a different app that I cannot modify. Once started, my app needs a token, like a password, to connect to a web service. As it is now, I can only make ajax requests from the parent window but not from the child window. This is why I have to pass the token from the parent window to the child.

I'll disagree with the comments saying that there is no secure content in front-end: It all depends on the threat model.
If we talk about an adversary having physical access to the computer or even just with dev-tools level clearance (e.g. a browser extension), then indeed you can't consider anything secure. We need to assume they can just intercept anything in  memory / displayed on screen / going through the network. But thinking this way is futile. Would you leave your home's doors wide open at all time just because someone could anyway dig a hole in the walls?
If your threat is an external page being able to read your data, then it's secure. Even the fact of having it as a global on your opener is also secure. Cross-origin pages won't be able to access your page's globals.
If the adversary has access to your page and its globals, then they can also access all of your page's resources and thus to the very sensible data you're trying to protect. I.E. you're already doomed. Using postMessage is no more secure in such a case, they can override it and grab all the data you pass to it. Server-side session isn't much more secure either. Since they could access your page's global, they can also access the popup's global (e.g. they can override window.open() if needed), and they'll get access to all the data fetched from that popup. They can even impersonate both your pages since they have access to your fetch() method, from your origin. Your server would have no mean to know that it's not talking to you.
So instead of trying to hide your data, prevent your adversaries to gain access to your page: avoid untrusted scripts to run on your page, and sandbox all your iframes.
Now, globals are bad for other reasons, so you may want to use another mean of accessing that key. Server-side sessions seem to be a decent solution for the case as you've presented it. Another way to pass data between an opener and a same-origin popup is to declare a function in the popup and call it from the opener (somehow I personally find it cleaner to have functions as globals rather than values). And for cross-origin pages you have postMessage().
